# TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Tags: javascript, permissions, discord.js

I was trying to make a const member but it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined"

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'welcome',
    description: 'welcome',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        const member = message.mentions.users.first();

        if(message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('title')
                .setImage('imageurl')
                .setDescription('desc')
            )
        }else{
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have any permissions to do that!`)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because 'message.mentions' is undefined

Comment: What is the purpose of that line anyway? The variable `member` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: You ,most likely got `    execute(message, args, Discord) {` message, args, Discord out of order, and so your "message" is not really a Discord.Js Message

Answer (score 0):

As Trever Thompson has commented. It is because you aren't mentioning anyone. I have tested it and it works. Here is what you should use:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'welcome',
    description: 'welcome',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!member) { // If a user is not mentioned
message.channel.send(`Hey ${message.author} you need to mention a user to welcome!`)
return false; // < Even after it checks if a user is mentioned or not, use return false; This will prevent you from getting error of `users` being undefined
}
        if(message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('title')
                .setImage('imageurl') 
                .setDescription('desc')
            )
        }else{
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have any permissions to do that!`)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because mentions is undefined, you can ignore this error by adding a question mark behind mentions.

```
const member = message?.mentions?.users.first();
```